# Return Image SRC from ALTSRC once Clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I get the IMAGE in the DIV it lies in to return to the original image SRC once clicked on a different item?

To understand what I mean, click here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fAmWx/7/

You can see that when you click on another Accordian Item, the image doesn't return to it's original state. I have outlined the jQuery/JavaScript within the jsFiddle.

Thank you so much!

Comment: For me it works fine as expected. I can see the image src toggles.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: What I mean is for example: You click on the second EXPAND DIV you see the CONTENT DIV residing in the ITEM DIV. So that is the current DIV (in a sense), then you click on the FIRST EXPAND DIV to see the CONTENT DIV residing in the ITEM DIV. The second CONTENT DIV closes, but the image does not revert to it's original source, instead of keeps the ALTSRC image. How can I set it up to where when I different DIV is selected the previous DIVs ALT Image is reverted back to the ORIGINAL SRC image? Oh wow, if that makes sense lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo as per your requirements :

http://jsfiddle.net/fAmWx/9/

Comment: That did not do the trick, I see what you tried doing though.